# Why does my code not work (Count occurrence of a character in a string)

Tags: nasm

I'm trying to count occurrence of a '.' character, but my code won't work (result is 0, no matter how many dots there are). What's wrong?

```
global _main
extern _printf
extern _scanf

section .data
text: db "One. Two, Three, Four. Five.", 0
txtlen: equ $-text
format: db "%d", 0

section .text
_main:
mov al, '.'
mov cx, txtlen
lea di, [text]
xor ebx, ebx
B:
repne scasb 
jcxz A 
inc ebx
jmp B
A:
push ebx
push format
call _printf
add esp, 8

mov eax, 4C00h
ret
```

Comment: You're mixing 16-bit and 32-bit code. That's asking for trouble. Please show your commands to assemble and link the source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
lea edi, [text]
```

Well. There I go